# Sharepoint list items increase

Tags: 2010, list, column

I have around 50,000 items in sharepoint list . I want to increase the size of the list items to 90,000 . It is ok to have duplicate enteries . How do i do it with minimal time ?

Its ok if i paste the same data in the list .

Comment: Unless these are in folders, you are really pushing the limits of what SharePoint should be doing with a list. You may want to consider alternative options such as a proper database application.

Comment: Yes i do have a folder structure for the list .

Comment: You can have duplicate entries (it assigns each entry a unique ID anyways). I'm not sure why you would want to re-paste the same data, but yes you can do that and using datasheet view is the fastest method short of code.

Comment: I want to test performance of app with having large data in list . I know i can write a PS and get it done . But is there a easy way ?

Comment: I'm not a PS junkie, so I would use a little javascript to write entries in a loop. Would it be faster? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell Script to dump all the folders in same list and increase the size from 50K to 90K.

```
function Copy-ItemsToFolder([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$folder, $srcList, $destList)
{
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.Folder = $folder


$sourceSPListItemCollection = $srcList.GetItems($spQuery);
$destFolder = $destList.Folders[$folder.Name];
if ($destFolder -eq $null -or $destFolder -eq "")
{
    #folder does not exist so create it.
    $destFolder = $destList.AddItem("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder)
    $destFolder["Title"] = $folder.Name + "_3";
    $destFolder.Update()
}
$count = $sourceSPListItemCollection.Count;
$index = 0;
$newFolderPath = $destFolder.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl
foreach($srcListItem in $sourceSPListItemCollection)
{
    $index++;

    write-host "adding new item $index of $count";
    $newSPListItem = $destList.AddItem($newFolderPath, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::File, $null);

    foreach($spField in $srcListItem.Fields)
    {
        if ($spField.ReadOnlyField -ne $True -and $spField.InternalName -ne "Attachments")
        {
            $newSPListItem[$spField.InternalName] = $srcListItem[$spField.InternalName];
        }
    }
    $newSPListItem.Update()
    write-host "added";
}
}
try
{
$srcListSiteUrl = "https://sitename/abc/"
$SourceListName = "lsitname"

$dstListSiteUrl = "https://sitename/abc/"
$DestinationListName = "lsitname"

$keyColumnInternalName = "Title"

$sourceListWeb = Get-SPWeb -identity $srcListSiteUrl
$sourceListUrl = $sourceListWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/" + $SourceListName;

$dstListWeb = Get-SPWeb -identity $dstListSiteUrl
$destinationListUrl = $dstListWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/" + $DestinationListName;

$SourceList = $sourceListWeb.GetList($sourceListUrl);
$DestinationList = $dstListWeb.GetList($destinationListUrl);

foreach($currentFolder in $SourceList.RootFolder.SubFolders)
{
    Write-Host "processing folder $($currentFolder.Name)";

    if ($currentFolder.ItemCount -gt 0)
    {
        Copy-ItemsToFolder $currentFolder $SourceList $DestinationList
    }
    Write-Host "done with folder"
}

}

catch
{
write-host $_.exception
}

finally
{
if($sourceListWeb -ne $null){$sourceListWeb.Dispose()}
if($dstListWeb -ne $null){$dstListWeb.Dispose()}
}
```